rEFInd Boot manager isnt working
rEFInd is not working correctly as it displays a blank white screen with just it's logo "rEFInd Boot Manager" and basically nothing else i can not open any OS nor can i shut down nor reboot or anything, my only option was to go to UEFI and boot up windows since ubuntu boot turned into rEFInd Boot and i tried downloading rEFInd from every source i could find, i downloaded it as a deb, from terminal and tried from a bootable usb but every time i load rEFInd its just a white blank screen and the only words return are rEFInd boot manager and the blue magnifying glass and nothing else, I'm new to linux as a whole and don't know where the issue could even come fromd

You mention "since ubuntu boot turned into rEFInd Boot" which makes little sense; Ubuntu uses grub (GNU Boot loader) as its bootloader and not rEFIind for all releases (you mostly talk of Linux, giving few specific details for us to provide specific help)
